# loopback.js, one API for different projects, structure and project inheritance

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to developp a rest API using loopback.js, which seems to be a good solution, but my case is a bit special.

- my rest api must serve differents projects: for example:
  http://mydomain/project-1/api/documents
  http://mydomain/project-2/api/documents
  http://mydomain/project-3/api/documents
- each of my projects (project-1, project-2) have more or less the same core structure (a "document" table, a "article" table, etc...)
- each of my projects must inherit this core structure but can expand it with fields, models, ...

I thought I could use loopback.js to define a core description of my database, and extend my descriptions using inheritance for instance to describe instance projects database, and choose the right database/models to use on the flight.

Three questions so:

- Do you think loopback.js is the right nodejs solution to do so or is there a better option?
- is it possible to create a core definition of my base/models and extend it for each project, only dedefining what is différent?
- how and where would you set the database/models to use on the flight by parsing the url and having the same api serving all my projects?

It is a loopback.js newbie question, but I can't find any other question/response on the subject. If you having any example of something similar in nodejs, I would be gratefull!

Thanks a lot!

Pierre.

Comment: Oh! Buddy the question is too broad. Frankly I don't think anybody bothers to figure out the question. All I can do is upvote your question, which I did!

Comment: yes I know... I thought maybe someone could have done this kind of thing... anyway, I think typeorm will make the job. I kind of managed to do it with loopback but i'm not convinced, seems too hacky. Anyway, thanks a lot :)